# Specifying multiple Eclipse's Make Targets with control of order/dependence?

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

Is there any way to specify multiple Make Targets to be built by the build process, and if so, then it is possible to control the order or define dependence of the Make Targets in a managed C++ project?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in eclipse and at the command line, I'd edit the makefile to add a targets depending on the items. Make will figure out the order if needed.

If it's ok to have this work just in the Eclipse project then add a custom make target
In the "Make Target" view, click "Create a Make Target", uncheck "Same as Target Name".
List your multiple dependencies all in the "make target" edit box.

Comment: I don't want to have to mess with creating and managing my own Makefile, so I'd prefer to not have to walk down that road.